# Different Pods using same socket

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kubernetes-ingress, kubernetes-pod, kubernetes-service

I need to have two kubernetes pods podA and podB which are used for receiving inTraffic and sending outTraffic respectively. The end customer who is a client uses a single socket for both sending and receiving traffic from my application (which has podA and podB running together). I want to have a service in between the end customer and my application which can handle this, meaning the inbound traffic comes from the customer through the service to podA, while the traffic sent from the application (podB) goes through the service and finally reaches the customer.

The customer has only one socket connection established to the service but in the backend, two pods needs to talk to the service.

Can this be achieved and if yes, how to configure the service on kubernetes. 
My cloud environment is AWS.

Answer (score 0):

No, that is not how sockets work. There’s probably some technically valid solution involving bpf programs but seriously you need to rethink your networking architecture :)